# How do I extract text and numbers from a string within a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I intend to extract text and numbers within a cell for a matrix range obeying the spaces, example: {OPL;" "; SKY;" "; FORD} and {909;" "; 01245}, is there any way to obtain this result through any formula? Or if you don't really have a formula, is there any VBA code to do that?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following formula for the text elements:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A41,SEQUENCE(1,500),1))),MID(A41,SEQUENCE(1,500),1)," ")))," ",";"" "";")
```

and the following formula for numerical elements:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A41,SEQUENCE(1,500),1))," ")))," ",";"" "";")
```

Those will return exactly the form shown in the pic. If you really want `; ;` and not `;" ";` between elements when there are spaces, change the end of each formula from **,";"" "";")** to **,"; ;")**.

If you have a large number of cells to test, and you can be fairly sure of the number of characters in the longest, you could reduce the `SEQUENCE()` value. Or... make it greater if need be.

Or you can get slick and note it will take cell values or formulas for its arguments/parameters. If so, you could change the "500" to `LEN(A1)` (changing the "A1" to suit the formula's target, then copying and pasting or filling to make the formula change as needed for each other cell being examined.

Comment: My Excel doesn't have the "Sequence ()" function, so I used this formula: Row (indirect ("1:" & len (A1))). Well, I never had the idea of inserting the function "Mid" in the condition as true, I already had an idea of how to extract the characters, but they came out together without spaces, I used the "SUBSTITUTE (ADDRESS (ROW () ; COLUMN (A1: Z1); 4); ROW (); "") "and then made a comparison in the condition" If () "in the true result, this in the case of texts. Appreciate!

Comment: Her last formula to extract the numbers, almost worked, but she joins the numbers and I didn't insert the spaces in the middle to identify each number "90901245",
when it deems it to be "909 01245", however the space is text and he considered it as an error. But I managed to solve it, but the formula increased in size and became more complex

Comment: TRIM(TEXTJOIN("";1;IF(ISERROR(IF((MID(A41;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A41)));1)+0)<>"";MID(A41;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A41)));1);""));" ";IF((MID(A41;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A41)));1)+0)<>"";MID(A41;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A41)));1);""))))